# CSS font sizing relative to parent

Tags: css, responsive-design

Is there a font sizing unit in CSS that allows me to specify sizes relative to the parent element;

`vw` and `vh` for example are relative to the viewport width and height respectively.

I want a parent relative size for a responsive design. Say for example my parent element is `400px` wide, I want my text to be half of that width, but I'm not sure if I can specify this - or even if such a feature would be widely supported.

Comment: You'll need Javascript for this.

Comment: if you search around on SO, you'll see many results, but no pure CSS solution AFAIK, perhaps to use viewport units for all. A side note, font-size:200px doesn't mean height is 200px.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Just use the font-size value ising em instead of px or pt. For example, if you have a div with a width and height of 400px, use a font-size: XXem (where xx is the numeric value). Alternately, you can also include a % in your font size as well.

Comment: But it's not a responsive size. What happens when your div is 50% of the viewport width?

Comment: Then it may be appropriate to use em values to declare that the font size is only a portion of the % width.

Answer (score 0):

I just came across this issue, and this is my solution to it:

```
:root{
    --some-width: 228pt;
}
.someElement{
    font-size: calc(var(--some-width) / X);
}
```

Replace X with a number.

In my case is useful because I need the same thing multiple times but in different sizes.

Answer (score -1):

In this case, you should use the **em** value on the child elements.

**One em (1em) is equal to the current font size.** So for example, if the parent element has the font size of 16px than 1em is equal to 16px, 2em is equal to 32px and so on…